# Aggregate data based on values appearing in two columns interchangeably?

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions

```
      home_team_name     away_team_name  home_ppg_per_odds_pre_game  away_ppg_per_odds_pre_game
0  Manchester United  Tottenham Hotspur                    3.310000                    4.840000
1    AFC Bournemouth        Aston Villa                    0.666667                    3.230000
2       Norwich City     Crystal Palace                    0.666667                   13.820000
3     Leicester City         Sunderland                    4.733333                    3.330000
4            Everton            Watford                    0.583333                    2.386667
5            Chelsea  Manchester United                    1.890000                    3.330000
```

The `home_ppg_per_odds_pre_game` and `away_ppg_per_odds_pre_game` are basically the same metric. The former reprsents the value of this metric for the home_team, while the latter represents this metric for the away team. I want a mean of this metric for each team and that is regardless whether the team is playing home or away. In the example df you Manchester United as home_team_name in zero and as away_team_name in 5. I want the mean for Manchester United that includes all this examples.

```
df.groupby("home_team_name")["home_ppg_per_odds_pre_game"].mean()
```

This will only bring me the mean for the occasion when the team is playing home, but I want both home and away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the two metrics are the same, you can append the home and away team metrics, like this:

```
data_df = pd.concat([df.loc[:,('home_team_name','home_ppg_per_odds_pre_game')], df.loc[:,('away_team_name','away_ppg_per_odds_pre_game')].rename(columns={'away_team_name':'home_team_name','away_ppg_per_odds_pre_game':'home_ppg_per_odds_pre_game'})])
```

Then you can use `groupby` to get the means:

```
data_df.groupby('home_team_name')['home_ppg_per_odds_pre_game'].mean().reset_index()
```

Comment: Good answer. Please explain in text solution you propose for future readers to follow.